# Clustering EJB Session Beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

Does EJB have clustering defined I have found clustering the Stateless or Statefull beans are platform specific for ex. Jboss has 
@Clustered annotation and Optimized interface that helps with clustering beans across servers, is it because EJB spec hasn't defined clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, clustering is not a part of the EJB specification and indeed is vendor-specific. As mentioned in [J2EE and Beyond book](https://books.google.com/books?id=KFaY1iXxhnMC&pg=PA572&dq=ejb+specification+clustering&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi49cSv-9TMAhVkG5oKHVl7C3wQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=ejb%20specification%20clustering&f=false):

> A few of the more important features that are not addressed directly by the EJB specification are server clustering and and component failover...
>
> In order to provide both failover and scalability, application server vendors allow clusters or groups of hardware servers running the same software to be addressed as a server cluster.